# Why is MySQL using filesort when there is no ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, optimization

All,

I'm trying to resolve some performance problems and I've got as far as analyzing this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT entry.entry_key, entry.node, entry.object_type, entry.object_id,
               entry.copy_id, entry.seq_number, entry.root_seq_number, entry.first_error,
               entry.last_error, entry.error_count, entry.error_id, entry.error_code,
               entry.status, entry.type, entry.sense, entry.reviewed 
       FROM eventlog me  JOIN eventlog_entry eventlog_entries 
            ON eventlog_entries.eventlog_key = me.eventlog_key  JOIN entry entry 
            ON entry.entry_key = eventlog_entries.entry_key 
       WHERE ( ( ( first_error >= '0' AND last_error <= '2147483640' ) AND 
                   me.eventlog_key = '1' ) ) 
       GROUP BY entry.entry_key\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: me
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: eventlog_entries
         type: ref
possible_keys: eventlog_entry_idx_entry_key,eventlog_entry_idx_eventlog_key
          key: eventlog_entry_idx_eventlog_key
      key_len: 8
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra:
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: entry
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: eventlog.eventlog_entries.entry_key
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The *original* query did have an `ORDER BY` in it, but I removed that. However, `EXPLAIN` is still reporting a filesort and I can't figure out why. Has the MySQL optimizer cached the optimization somewhere? Or is filesort used for some other reason too?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MySQL will sort by default whenever you do a `GROUP BY`. To avoid this, just add `ORDER BY NULL`.

Comment: That's great. Out of interest, is that documented somewhere?

Comment: Found it in `SELECT` documentation: "If you use GROUP BY, output rows are sorted according to the GROUP BY columns as if you had an ORDER BY for the same columns. To avoid the overhead of sorting that GROUP BY produces, add ORDER BY NULL"